# Show wordpress daily posts according to timestamp custom dates

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i can't figure out how to list daily posts according to date when the date is saved as timestamp in DB.
So i have got a code like:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 150,           
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'meta_key' => 'event_datetime',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_value' => '1582509700',             
            'post_status' => 'publish'

        );
```

The meta_value is pasted from one certain post, but, how to show all posts from the day by timestamp? Somebody was on to this maybe?

Comment: If you're using ACF read this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/ `The value selected can be returned and displayed in different formats but will be saved to the database as ‘Ymd’` not in epoch time

Comment: nope, i have a custom modification - it is stored in timestamp already in DB

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though what you're looking for is the `meta_query` "Between" comparison.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_datetime',
            'value' => array($start_timestamp, $end_timestamp),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    ),
);
```